# Conflict when using annotation @Scheduled and @Before in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, schedule

I'm having a Component in spring boot like this :

```
@Component
public class A{}
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
public void B{
.......
 List<Database> databases = databaseServiceImpl.getDatabases(a,b,c);
}
```

databaseServiceImpl is a service which has structure like this

```
@Service
public class DatabaseServiceImpl{
@Override
  public Database getDatabases(a,b,c){
}
}
```

Method getDatabases is going with an AOP method like this

```
 @Before("execution(* .....DatabaseServiceImpl.*(..))")
  public void getSystemType(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
....
}
```

And when I'm running my spring boot project, there is an error:

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
> outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
> the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
> a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
> running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use
> RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
> request

What should I do to solve this conflict, thank you so much

Comment: The error already tells you what to do. You have request (or session) scoped beans which you are accessing from a non web context (the scheduler).